# Where to update new PAS token from MS DevOps in my Angular 2+ source code?

Tags: azure-devops, token, access-token

I have a Personal Access Token about to expire in DevOps/VSTS, but I can't see it in DevOps to do a ctrl-f and find it in my source code.

I have an Angular 2+ frontend with a .net core api backend.

Which file should I be looking at? Does it need to go in the backend? Or Frontend? Or both?

config.json? project.json? Which property is it (if it is a config file like that)?

Or is it somewhere else I need to update this?  Not in source code, but something with the build agent? How would I update that?!

Answer (score 0):

> Which file should I be looking at? Does it need to go in the backend?

Since we could not clearly know how is your script look like, I assume you may not remember clearly about this because of huge script files. For this, Azure Devops has a feature [Search](http://Search%20across%20all%20your%20code,%20wiki,%20packages%20and%20work%20items) can search what you want across all your code.

[image]

For any repos which with a api called, we suggest you search the code files first with **Search feature**. And also, you may pass the token value with task variable. So, you also need to check your pipeline variable.

Comment: Yes this is what I want to do. But I wouldn't know know the value of the current token to search for. Not do I know a name of a property value it may be. I did also check variables in pipelines but nothing stood out to me. I am actually starting to think the PAS is used when setting up and configuring a build agent. So maybe I need to regenrate the token, reconfigure the build agent, and when promoted, supply the new token.

Comment: For the token you used to configure the build agent, you do not need worry about expired. The token **just used for register** the agent into pool. After that, it will not has effect any more, unless you delete the agent from the pool.

Comment: The api you used in your script is Client api?